# Not working plugins with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This code have an ajax script that delete a record and have an animation when deleting. But when I mix the ajax script with plugins confirm it's not working. What is the problem with this script?

This is the delete button in my table record.

```
<?php
echo'   <tr class="record"> 
    <td align="center"><a href="#" id="'.$row["counter"].'" class="delbutton"><img src="images/del.png"></a></td></tr>';
?>
```

Ajax with confirm plugins

```
  <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".delbutton").click(function(){
            var element = $(this);
            var del_id = element.attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + del_id;
            $(function() {
    $("<div />").attr("id", "dialog-confirm").append(
        $("<p />").text('Are you sure?').css("text-align", "center").prepend(
            $("<span />").addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-alert").css({
                display: 'inline-block',
                margin: '0px 7px 0px 0px'
            })
        )
    ).dialog({
                  resizable: false,
                  height:140,
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                    "Delete all items": function() {                           
                       $.ajax({
                         type: "GET",
                         url: "delete.php",
                         data: info,
                         success: function(){
                            $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
                         }
                       }); 
                       $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                      return false;
                    }
                  }
                }); // end Dialog         
            return false;
        }); // end .delbtn
        });
    }); // end jquery load
  </script>
```

Comment: Where is this `<script>` tag, and the rest of your `<script>` tags? If in the `<head>` tag then you should use `$(document).ready()`. If your plugin is from another non-jQuery library then use `$.noConflict()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ .

Answer (score 0):

i copy your code and do a test , it's useful!  so , please check the file sequence, i do like this:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: sometimes it works but when it failed to execute this message is in console TypeError: $(...).attr(...).append(...).dialog is not a function

Comment: do you hava import Library ?

Comment: um..create a new file and set clear code in new file try it ,that is  all  I can  help,please step by step debugging